# Reverse Engineering A RS-485 Steam Shower Protocol

Tags: serial-communication, protocol, communication

**Scenario:**
A residential steam shower with a control box, touch pad display, and single input contact sensor on a half-duplex, RS-485 daisy chained network.

**Goal:**
Determine RS-485 based Link Layer from serial capture.

**Help:**
Are my assumptions reasonable? Is it polling? Time slotted? Tokenized? 1 Bit Sliding Window? What should be my next steps? Did I leave out any critical information in my question? Any theories on the origin of the magic numbers?

**Details:**
I googled all aspects of the system in an attempt to find known information (control boards, brand names, etc.) I came up with so little that I might be the only fool trying to do this (how many geeks own steam showers?)

Using an oscilloscope, baud was found to be 62.5K with UART packets of N,8,1.

Only two message types witnessed:

- Message type "5A4A".

  - With the system at rest, most messages are of type “5A4A”
  - Assumed format of: 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58

    - Magic Number: 5A4A
    - Address1: C1
    - MsgLen : 04 (Including this field)
    - Address2: C1
    - Data: 00
    - CRC: 58
  - Additional Details:

    - Data lengths are always 4 of 5 bytes
    - Addr1 is always A1, B1, B2, or C1
    - Addr2 is always C1 or C2
    - Most common combinations occur about every 100ms (1467 counts in 156 seconds):

      - A1,C2
      - C1,C1
    - Occurred 96 in 156 seconds:

      - A1,C1
    - Occurred 32 in 156 seconds:

      - B1, C1
      - B2, C1
- Message type “4154” appears to give larger payloads of data.

  - Example: 4154:31:0A:060000000000000000:50

    - Magic Number: 4154
    - Address1: 31
    - MsgLen: 0A (NOT including this field)
    - Data: 060000000000000000
    - CRC: 50
- Capture Sample:

  - 07:38:10.638 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:10.734 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:10.734 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:10.830 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:10.846 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:10.926 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:10.942 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:10.974 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:10.990 4154:33:05:01030521:3B
  - 07:38:11.038 4154:31:03:0800:92
  - 07:38:11.038 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.133 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.133 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.229 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.245 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.325 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.341 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.389 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.405 5A4A:B1:05:C1:0005:C4
  - 07:38:11.421 5A4A:A1:04:C1:00:C8
  - 07:38:11.421 5A4A:B2:05:C1:0005:8A
  - 07:38:11.453 5A4A:A1:04:C1:00:C8
  - 07:38:11.453 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.501 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.501 4154:C1:05:04000A01:65
  - 07:38:11.517 4154:31:0A:060000000000000000:50
  - 07:38:11.533 4154:33:05:01030521:3B
  - 07:38:11.549 4154:31:03:0800:92
  - 07:38:11.565 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
  - 07:38:11.645 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
  - 07:38:11.645 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
- Hints:

  - Sensor and Display are silent when separated from the control box but can be stimulated to respond once (but not repetitively per packet) as stimulated below:

    - Writing: 5A4AC104C10058
    - 4154:31:03:0800:92
    - Writing: 5A4AB105C10000FB
    - 5A4A:A1:04:C2:00:9D
    - Writing: 5A4AB205C10000B5
    - 5A4A:A1:04:C1:00:C8
  - Monitoring the isolated control box, continual traffic of:

    - 14:02:10.363 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:10.459 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:10.570 5A4A:B1:05:C1:0000:FB
    - 14:02:10.666 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:10.763 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:10.858 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:10.970 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.066 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.162 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.258 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.370 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.466 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.562 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:11.674 5A4A:B2:05:C1:0000:B5
    - 14:02:11.770 4154:C1:05:04000A01:65
    - 14:02:11.866 4154:33:05:01030521:3B
    - 14:02:11.978 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.074 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.170 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.266 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.378 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.474 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.570 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58
    - 14:02:12.666 5A4A:C1:04:C1:00:58

Thanks!